# visibility hidden vs -webkit-transform: translate3d() in phonegap application

Tags: javascript, css, cordova

So I am using phonegap to create a hybrid application. Now obviously I have many divs(page size) that I hide and show using css "visibility: hidden and visible" property. I read somewhere that by using -webkit-transform: translate3d() I can hide the divs offscreen and show them again when needed and that this technique is much better. Does anyone know is this really true or not?

Comment: My honest advice: Always use a framework for phonegap applications!
While I still think that the ionic framework will be the better choice for future apps, currently the only framework I can recommend perfomance wise is KendoUI Mobile.

This way you can concentrate on your app instead of concerning yourself with questions like these. Creating nice looking animations with CSS3 takes a lot of work and frameworks like these have usually already nice looking animations and transitions.

Comment: I have only 6 different pages, and I think the framework will only slow down the app. what do you think?

Comment: If you don't want to trouble yourself with any framework and don't plan on further working on it, you should be fine without. As for the framework slowing the app down, this would probably be true for jQuery Mobile but definitely not KendoUI Mobile. They only "problem" with KendoUI is that it's not free.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason why anyone would want to use translations instead of standard visibility or display attributes is perception of performance. One can control exactly how a transition from one state to another state performs. A good example is mobile apps where transitions with animations are very popular.

If you want to use it within your app and do not need third party controls or out of the box MV** support, take a look at the Famo.us framework (http://famo.us/). While it lucks controls, it is very fast, uses transformations and incapsulates browser details.

Kendo UI Mobile is another good framework. It is a MV** framework, has a reasonable set of controls and ability to control look and feel. While it is a complete framework, one can integrate it with with Knockout and AngularJS.

And of course, give it try to Ionic (http://ionicframework.com/) and see if it is fast enough for you.

In any case, it is the best to use some framework and not use it directly. It is a lot of work to do otherwise correctly.